# Pythonic way of calculating difference between nth and n-1th value in a large dataframe using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a 100x100 pandas dataframe, consisting entirely of numerical values.

What I want to do is get the difference in each column for the nth row and n-1th row:

Let's say the first column has values (1,2,3,4.....100) what I would want is the output (1,1,1,1,1,1,1.....1) it would subtract the first row from the second row, the second row from the third etc....for each column.

I have done it using a for-loop where it loops through each column, then each row. But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution

This is what I figure will work, haven't actually had a chance to try it yet for reasons....

```
outputframe = pd.DataFrame(data=0, index = list(range(1,99)), column = list(range(1,100))
For i in range(0,100):
    For x in range(1,100):
       outputframe.iloc[x,i]= df.iloc[x,i]-df[x-1,i]
```

I believe this will give me the correct results, however, I'm wondering if there's possibly a more elegant solution

Comment: You should look pandas shift

Comment: Or in this case simply `.diff()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the key here is the pandas `shift(n)` method, which allows you to shift the index by `n` rows.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 100)))
df_new = df.shift(-1) - df
```

Comment: Bingo. I knew there had to a better way, so elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like @ALollz says `.diff()` will work fine and fast here. 
First row will get NaNs so I'm reassigning the first row again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 100)))
df_new = df.diff()
df_new.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0]
```

Original dataframe

[image]

After .diff() (NaN on first row)

[image]

After `df_new.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0]`

[image]